# How to map an array in a Firestore document to Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

How can I map the arrays in the following Firestore documents to Swift?

[image: Firestore Document]

Here is my data model in Swift:

```swift
  import Foundation
    
  struct CityList: Codable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var latitude: String
    var longitude: String
  }
    
  struct Cities: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var citiesList: [CityList]
  }
```

and here is my view model:

```swift
class WeatherList: ObservableObject {

  @Published var cities = [CityList]()
    
  func fetchCities(userInfo: UserInfo) {
    self.cities.removeAll()
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
      .collection("cities")
      .document(userInfo.user.uid)
       
    db.getDocument() { (document, error) in
      if let document = document, document.exists {
        guard let itemIDs = document.get("citiesList") else { 
          return 
        }
        for i in itemIDs {
          print(i.value)
        }
      } 
      else { 
        return 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When executed, it displays an error: `Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Sequence'`

How can I map this document?

Comment: You're not doing any conversion of the document data to `CityList` yet -- check out the section in the documentation on Custom Objects: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I'm curious: do you have more than one document in your cities collection? And why have you chosen an array of cities instead of one document per city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, just need to call `data(as:)` to perform the mapping.

Here is the updated code:

```swift
import Foundation
    
struct City: Codable, Hashable {
  var name: String
  var latitude: String
  var longitude: String
}
    
struct Cities: Codable, Identifiable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var cities: [City]
}
```

```swift
class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var cities = [City]()

  func fetchCities(userInfo: UserInfo) {
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore()
      .collection("cities")
      .document(userInfo.user.uid)


    docRef.getDocument { document, error in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        self.errorMessage = "Error getting document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
      }
      else {
        if let document = document {
          do {
            let citiesDocument = try document.data(as: Cities.self)
            self.cities = citiesDocument.cities
          }
          catch {
            print(error)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For a comprehensive overview of how to map Firestore data to / from Swift, check out my blog post [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift - The Comprehensive Guide](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide)